# Can I back up data on PS4?

Tags: ps4

I was wondering if it was possible to back up data on PS4 in case my account got deleted. If it is possible, do you have any suggestions on how?

Comment: What "data" are you trying to backup? Savegames? No problem. Games? It's possible, but you won't be able to play them without the account that bought them. Why do you expect your account to be deleted anyway?

Comment: I'm mostly trying to back up data from fallout 4, so, yeah, savegames. The reason I'm trying to back it up is - yes, you'll laugh, and yes, it's stupid - is because my brother actually owns the PS4, and he threatens to delete my account if I do anything to bother him. He's already done it once before, and I couldn't handle all my work being lost _again_.

Comment: If you've got a PS Plus subscription, you can easily backup to the Cloud (which is automatic), otherwise, you need a USB stick. How to copy save games to a USB storage device, is described [**here**](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2013/12/25/how-to-backup-and-transfer-ps4-game-saves-using-a-usb-drive/).

Answer (score 1):

As commented by [Nolonar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/46740/nolonar), you can [copy save files to a USB storage device](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2013/12/25/how-to-backup-and-transfer-ps4-game-saves-using-a-usb-drive/) or, if you are a PS+ Subscriber, to the cloud.